# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-99ba79ecbbfb> in <module>
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    172 
    173 
--> 174 _check_versions()
    175 
    176 

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _check_versions()
    157     # Quickfix to ensure Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable
    158     # DLLs are loaded before importing kiwisolver
--> 159     from . import ft2font
    160 
    161     for modname, minver in [

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by downgrading to matplotlib 3.0.3

```
conda uninstall matplotlib

conda install matplotlib==3.0.3
```